# scheduler job to copy an entire DB to another DB in the same server

Tags: sql-server-2012, copy, scheduler, jobs

Would like to create a daily scheduler job for sql server in a cloud environment, so that it copy an entire DB to another existing DB in the same server. Please someone advise with the steps.

Comment: You mean take a backup? Or replication? By cloud, you mean Azure, or another one? Google for SQL Server backup (or replication, depending what exactly you want to do), and the name of your cloud environment.

Comment: It is Azure environment. I have DB - "A" and everyday as a nightly job, I would like to copy or replicate the entire content of DB - "A" to another existing DB - "ABackUp" in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: We already having a nightly job for .bak for this DB - "A". We are looking to restore or copy the entire DB regularly as a nightly job just as a mitigation plan. As this DB is CMS related, so this DB is edited by mulitiple people. So in case of any issues, we would like to switch the connection of latest readily available version we have.

Comment: so either create a job to restore the mentioned backup file elsewhere, or implement replication, it's up to you